# Standard document library not being found by Sharepoint Online Powershell Module?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, microsoft365

I am trying to delete file versions based on a timestamp for a document library on a Sharepoint site.

I keep getting the error "List 'Documents' does not exist at site with URL 'https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXXX'.", even though this is a standard library of my site. When I try to use the script for a library that I created ("Test"), it works. It won't work for any standard Sharepoint site library though.

Here's my script:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Config Parameters
$SiteURL= "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXXX"
 
#Setup Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)

# Define the timestamp - adjust this to your needs
$cutOffTimestamp = Get-Date "2015-08-30 09:25:00"

Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred

    # Get the document library by its title
    $libraryTitle = "Documents"  # Change this to the title of your library
    $library = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($libraryTitle)
    $Ctx.Load($library)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    # Get all files from the library
    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $items = $library.GetItems($query)
    $Ctx.Load($items)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    foreach ($item in $items) {
        $file = $item.File
        $Ctx.Load($file)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        # Get all versions of the file
        $versions = $file.Versions
        $Ctx.Load($versions)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        $versionsToDelete = @()

        # Loop through versions and identify which ones to delete based on timestamp
        foreach ($version in $versions) {
            if ($version.Created -lt $cutOffTimestamp) {
                $versionsToDelete += $version
            }
        }

        # Delete the identified versions
        foreach ($versionToDelete in $versionsToDelete) {
            $versionToDelete.DeleteObject()
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host -f Green "Deleted version $($versionToDelete.VersionLabel) of file $($file.Name) created on $($versionToDelete.Created)"
        }

        if ($versionsToDelete.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Host -f Yellow "No versions found before the given timestamp for file $($file.Name)!"
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error deleting versions based on timestamp!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

I used another script to get the name of all libraries for this site, which showed me that "Documents" does indeed exist. What is the problem?

I have tried this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224695/list-documents-does-not-exist-at-site-with-url-error-on-execute-query

It did not work. I have tried using the library name from the URL, which would be "Shared documents". I have tried different libraries and the only one that works is with the one I created, "Test".
This script also does not work for other Sharepoint sites I have full access and rights to.